# Ebay: Auth token is invalid. Validation of the authentication token in API request failed

Tags: php, ebay-api

I'm trying to use [Ebay PHP SDK](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php) to connect to Ebay and fetch sellers selling item. For this I used following steps:

Step 1: Get authorize token and code for logged-in user. I used following code to implement.

```
use \DTS\eBaySDK\OAuth\Services as OauthService;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\OAuth\Types as OauthType;

use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Enums;

$service = new OauthService\OAuthService([
    'credentials' => $config['sandbox']['credentials'],
    'ruName'      => $config['sandbox']['ruName'],
    'sandbox'     => true
]);
$oauthParam = [
  'client_id' => $config['sandbox']['credentials']['appId'],
  'redirect_uri' => $config['sandbox']['redirect_uri'],
  'response_type' => 'code',
  'scope' => 'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope'
];
$urlParam = '';
$query = [];
foreach($oauthParam as $key => $param) {
    $query[] = "$key=$param";
}
$urlParam = '?' . implode('&', $query);
$url = 'https://signin.sandbox.ebay.com/authorize' . $urlParam;
@session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['ebay_oauth_token'])) {
    $token = $_SESSION['ebay_oauth_token']['code'];
}
else {
    if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $token = $_GET['code'];
        $_SESSION['ebay_oauth_token']['code'] = $token;

        $request = new OauthType\GetUserTokenRestRequest();
        $request->code = $token;

        $response = $service->getUserToken($request);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
            //Error
        } else {
            $_SESSION['ebay_oauth_token']['access_token'] = $response->access_token;
        }
    } else {
        @header('location: ' . $url);
    }

}

$userOauthToken = $_SESSION['ebay_oauth_token']['access_token'];
```

The above code is working as expected. That is the user is redirected to Sign In Page to authorize himself and get the set of Code and Access Token.

Step 2: Fetch Selling Items using `code` obtained from `Step #1`. I've used following code to implement the functionality.

```
$request->RequesterCredentials = new Types\CustomSecurityHeaderType();
$request->RequesterCredentials->eBayAuthToken = $token; //Obtained from Step 1

$request->ActiveList = new Types\ItemListCustomizationType();
$request->ActiveList->Include = true;
$request->ActiveList->Pagination = new Types\PaginationType();
$request->ActiveList->Pagination->EntriesPerPage = 10;
$request->ActiveList->Sort = Enums\ItemSortTypeCodeType::C_CURRENT_PRICE_DESCENDING;

$pageNum = 1;

do {
    $request->ActiveList->Pagination->PageNumber = $pageNum;
    $response = $service->getMyeBaySelling($request);
    if (isset($response->Errors)) {
        //Error Output
    }

    if ($response->Ack !== 'Failure' && isset($response->ActiveList)) {
        foreach ($response->ActiveList->ItemArray->Item as $item) {
            //Output response
        }
    }

    $pageNum += 1;

} while ({condition});
```

I'm having problem in `Step #2`. It is generating `Invalid Token` while running the code.

I would highly appreciate if anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the requests. In the second part of your code, the request belongs to the Trading API that uses the Auth'n'Auth token, and you are trying to make the call using the OAuth token. These 2 tokens are different and work for different APIs.

You have 2 options.

1. Either keep the second part of your code, which appears to be correct, actually, but use the Auth'n'Auth token (that you can generate from the developer account). In this case, the first part is useless.
2. Keep the first part of your code, and delete the second part. In this case, you need to rewrite your second part of code using the OAuth API instead of the Trading API.